# What is the complexity of the cramer method?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra

I was reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692260/proof-complexity-cramers-theorem) which says that to solve the cramer method $(n + 1)$ operations are used.Then I thought that the complexity of using the equal method would be given by $ (n + 1) $, but apparently it is not. In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467019/is-cramers-rule-efficient-for-computational-point-of-view) they say that it is $ O (n! × n) $, but I don't know if I'm fine anymore. How can you get the value of the complexity of using the method?

Comment: they forgot an !

Comment: sorry, who forgot the !? and which part?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you compute the determinants. There are $(n+1)$ determinants in play. There are algorithms to compute determinants algebraically in $O(n^4)$, so you would get a total of $O(n^5)$ for Cramer.

But these algorithms compute at the same time as the determinant also the adjoint matrix, which means that all determinants for Cramer can be computed in $O(n^4)$.

Numerically, the best way to compute a determinant is via a LU or QR decomposition. As that also leads to an easy solver for the linear system, you could solve the task in $O(n^3)$

Comment: Im trying whit this method: $x_k= \frac{|A_k|}{|A|}$, used in $Ax=b$ systems

Comment: -Yes, that is Mr. Cramer's method. Using $n+1$ determinants, etc.

Comment: but wouldn't it be something like that?: finding the determinant of a n×n matrix, you need to find n! products. And since you need to find the determinants of n matrices, you need to do on the order of n!n multiplications.

Comment: And the complexity would be n! n, or not?

Comment: One usually does not chose the most wasteful computation method.

Comment: I agree, but would it be nice to say that the complexity of the method is n!n, or is this not true?